# A basis with rational entries for the Niemeier lattices

Tags: coding-theory, modular-forms, integer-lattices, string-theory

The [Niemeier lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niemeier_lattice) are defined to be the 24 even, self-dual lattices in 24 dimensions. Can anyone provide me with explicit bases for them, such that all the entries of the bases are rational numbers? Some basis are already given in the [catalogue of lattices](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/), but they either contain irrational entries or use matrices of dimensionality higher than 24, implementing the lattice as an appropriate subspace in a higher dimensional space, which is not what is wanted here. Is it possible to write down $24\times24$ matrices with rational entries that can be used as bases for the Niemeier lattices?

Comment: that is the choice in many case, either lowest dimension with irrational entries, or higher dimension. do you have SPLAG by Conway and Sloane?

Comment: @WillJagy I do, and I am aware of the construction using gluing vectors presented there, but as far as I can see this doesn't a priori exclude a different realization with rational entries. This is the reason I am asking here. Is it known if it is impossible to have such a realization?

Comment: I suppose I do not know for sure. However, for the hexagonal lattice in the plane that corresponds with packing circles, what would be your rational basis in $\mathbb R^2?$

Comment: @WillJagy I see your point. It is still not obvious that it is impossible but this has given me some food for thought. Thanks!

Comment: Every Niemeier lattices can be reached by a finite sequence of $2$-neigrhbor steps from $D_{24}^+$, and thus has a basis with rational (indeed dyadic) vectors in dimension $24$.